# Delete old version keep latest version in document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, document-library, version-history

I want to delete old version (0.5) and keep latest version (0.10) from a library.

How can I achieve it using PowerShell Script.

```
If(0.5 < 0.10)
{

 Remove version with 0.5 and keep 0.10
 But I doubt system takes 0.5 as 0.50 then the logic is not correct.

}
```

How can I get latest/current version number and delete older version?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use array index within the versions list like

```
for($i=$currentVersionsCount-1; $i -gt $versionstoKeep; $i--)
  {
   $SPItem.versions[$i].delete()
  }
```

Have a look at 
[sharepointdiary](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/01/limit-versioning-and-delete-old-versions-in-sharepoint.html) and
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231132/how-do-i-delete-version-history-files-in-sharepoint-online)

There you'll find the necessary hints.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is already to late for your project, but if someone has the same issue, you can use the tool DMS-Shuttle. It does exactly. Read that article: https://dms-shuttle.com/documentation/delete-version-history-in-sharepoint-online-office-365/
I am working for the vendor.